# How to make different records in one list view direct to different form views in odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo

I am looking for a better solution for the following situation:
Object A1, A2, A3... An, they have same attributes: a01, a02, a03, ... a0n. 
They have different attributes too:
    A1 has a10, a11, a12, ..., a1n, 
    A2 has a20, a21, a22, .... a2n, 
    A3 has a30, a31, a32, .... a3n, 
    An has an0, an1, an2, .... ann, 
Here is what to be expected:
One list view  displays values of attributes a01, a02, a03, ... a0n of all the objects(A1, A2, A3,...An).
When clicking a record in the list view, a form of that object will be opened and displayed. 
For example:
We have 3 records: 
    record 1 from object A1
    record 2 from object A2
    record 3 from object A3. 
So in the list view the value of attributes: 
    a01, a02, a03, ... a0n 
of all three records are displayed. 
When clicking record 1, the form of object A1 will be opened, and value of attributes a10, a11, a12, ..., a1n are displayed;
When clicking record 2, form of object A2 will be opened, and value of attributes a20, a21, a22, ..., a2n are displayed.
In other words, one list view will direct to different form views.
My current solution is all the attributes are merged into one module or class and all data is in one table. 
When clicking different records in the list view, the same form is displayed, most of the attributes are hide, it looks like a different view is displayed. 
When clicking record A1, a10, a11, a12, ... a1n are displayed, and a20, a21, a22, .... a2n,  an1, an2, .... ann, are hide.

The problem with this solution is the number of attributes in one module is becoming larger and larger, and  more and more attributes needs to be hide.
Do you have any idea to do this better?

Answer (score 1):

What about this you know that the tree views need only one model.

Instead of adding the all field in the merging model add common field and  the name of the model and the id of the recod in the original model. `(model_name, record_id)` show  a tree view that contains a button "Display record" the button calls a method to open the clicked record but in action dictionary returned by the model

```
      return {
             'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
              .......
              ........
             'view_ode': 'form',  # show the record in form view

            'res_model' : self.model_name,
            'res_id' : self.record_id,
        }
```

And this way you always show the original form view of the original model. And you need only one tree view for the merging model.

Don't show the form view of the mergin model you need to force the user to click on the button in tree view

```
          <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
```

I'm using my phone sorry for my english

Comment: Thanks a lot, that will solve a large part of the problem.